# [ HSQLDB]Violation of unique constraint

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, hsqldb

Here is my HSQLDB scripts

```
    CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AUTHORIZATION DBA
    CREATE MEMORY TABLE destinations (dID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, country VARCHAR(50), city VARCHAR(50))
    GRANT DBA TO SA
    SET WRITE_DELAY 20
    SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
    INSERT INTO destinations (dID, country, city) VALUES (100,  'Canada', 'Winnipeg')
```

it works fine with the above scripts. but if I want to add more scripts with

```
    INSERT INTO destinations (dI,Dcountry, city) VALUES (200,'Canada', 'Vancouvar')
```

it give error says

```
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Violation of unique constraint SYS_PK_49: duplicate value(s) for column(s) DID
```

I spend days with the error and couldn't figure out why. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Remove `dID` (and the value) from the `INSERT`; you don't need to define it as it's auto-generated.

Comment: I still got same error if I remove dID and value from insert : (

Comment: I assume this is because the auto-generated ids are colliding with ones you have explicitly specified previously. If this is a test/dev environment, could you just clean (`TRUNCATE`) the table and try again? Also, if you can share all code that's doing `INSERT`s to that table, we might be able to help you better.